# Entity Framework Connection String in App.Config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, app-config

I am very new to Entity Framework so apologies if this question is basic.

I am working through a Code First text book, and have created a small class library (c#) and a console app.  The text book indicates that when I run it Entity Framework will build the database in SQL server automatically.  It doesn't and the reason I believe is because I have a named instance rather than the default instance \SQLExpress.  The text book indicated I did not need a connection string when using the default instance, but since I am not using a default instance I am guessing I do need a connectionm string in App.Config.  I have tried putting a standard connection string in this file but it does not work.

Here are the entire contents of my App.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Could someone please advise where the connection string goes, or tell me if I am going about this the wrong way.

UPDATE

Thanks to the help received so far, my App.Config file now looks as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <configSections>    
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model" connectionString="Server=OFFICE-ACER\SQLE;Database=BreakAway;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

However, nothing happens i.e. no database is created as before.

Comment: You need a connection string. Also, the name of your connection string in the config is what you pass to your DBContext when you create an instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under your `<configSections>` tag, you can place this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConn" connectionString="theConnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then replace the values with what you need

Also although it may not help you in this situation, to avoid having to manually do this in future, the EntityFramework NuGet package works wonders, you just input the database's url and your login - then it creates the entire connection string for you in your config file, creates your edmx and allows you to import the data of your choice

Comment: This worked, but only after I changed "System.Data.EntityClient" to "System.Data.SqlClient".  Prior to that I was getting an error "keyword not supported 'server'".  Thanks for the help though - it got me to where I needed to be.

Comment: That's quite alright, sorry for not catching that one

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="putYourEntityName" connectionString="putYourConnectionStringHere" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb; but what is the Entity Name.  Is this the name of my context, the name of the DB, or the name of the class library project (or some other)?

Comment: @PJW Normally it is the same as the name of your `DbContext` class

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      ... 
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name" connectionString="Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog = yourDbName ; Intgrated Security ="According to your requirement" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

First thing that You need to know. If You are using a Class Library (.dll), the Entity (.edmx) file created inside the .dll, and You are invoking this Method, from an MVC Application (That have a web.config). The connection string inside of the App.config will never be used.

So You can have the Connection string mapped on the Web.Config (MVC Project), and even delete from the App.Config. It will always use the web.config.

Comment: There is no web.config file

Comment: I don't see any hints that this is a MVC application. Normally you need to define the connection string for the EDM where you use this model. That means, if you use a DLL which contains the EDM in an application, the connection string needs to be placed in the application's app-config not in the DLL's app-config