# Entity Framework connection string without password

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

before I was using a connection string with integrated security.
Now I switched it to username/password and created a new user in my SQL server.
I generated a new connection string with the server explorer in visual studio by adding a new connection (I didnt really added a connection there, I just used the wizard and copied the connection string for the app.config).
then I had to update-database and it worked.
But now I recognized that there is no password in my new connection string.
How does it work? I can't find the password anywhere...

Comment: check how your DB context is being initialized. You will get your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConnectionString loses password after connection.Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467335/connectionstring-loses-password-after-connection-open)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways: 

1: Add the string to the constructor of your Context.

```
public class Context: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext() : base("connectionstring") 
    {
    }
}
```

2: webconfig

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="putYourEntityName" connectionString="putYourConnectionStringHere" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As referenced from here: [Entity Framework Connection String in App.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262151/entity-framework-connection-string-in-app-config)